# When to perform host-ip based port mapping like "-p host-ip:port:port"

Tags: docker

Docker provides a way to map ports between the container and host.

As per the official [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports) its also possible to mention host-ip while port mapping.

`-p 192.168.1.100:8080:80` - Map TCP port 80 in the container to port 8080 on the Docker host for connections to host IP `192.168.1.100`.

I tried this option to figure out what's the difference with/without the host-ip.

- Using just `-p 80:80`

```
$ docker run -itd -p 80:80 nginx:alpine
$ curl localhost:80
$ curl 127.0.0.1:80
$ curl 0.0.0.0:80
$ curl 192.168.0.13:80
$ ps -ef | grep docker-proxy
16723 root      0:00 /usr/local/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 8080 -container-ip 172.17.0.1 -container-port 80
$
```

All the curl commands return the output.

- Using host-ip like `-p 192.168.0.13:80:80`

```
$ docker run -itd -p 192.168.0.13:80:80 nginx:alpine
$ curl localhost:80
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
$ curl 127.0.0.1:80
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused
$ curl 0.0.0.0:80
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 80: Connection refused
$ curl 192.168.0.13:80 # return output
$ ps -ef | grep docker-proxy
4914 root      0:00 /usr/local/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 192.168.0.13 -host-port 80 -container-ip 172.17.0.2 -container-port 80
$
```

All the `curl` commands failed except `192.168.0.13:80`.

Is there any there any other difference apart for the one I mentioned here.

Wondering when to use host-ip based port mapping. Any use cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A docker host may have multiple NICs. In the data center, this may be too segregate traffic, e.g. management, storage, and application/public. On your laptop, this may be for wireless and wired interfaces. There are also virtual NICs for things like loopback (127.0.0.1) and VPN tunnels.

When you do not specify an IP in the port publish command, by default docker will bind to all interfaces on the host. In IPv4, this is commonly notated as 0.0.0.0 which means listen on any interface (and this is why I don't connect *to* this address because there's no such thing as connecting *to* any IP). With the IP address specified, you manually specify which interface to use. Why would you want to specify this? Several reasons I can think of:

- Listening on only 127.0.0.1 to prevent external access
- Listening on 0.0.0.0 to explicitly bind to all IPv4 interfaces (it is possible to change docker's default behavior, so this could be necessary for some).
- Listening on one physical NIC, allowing other NICs to be bound by other services on the same port.
- Listening on only IPv4 interfaces if the app does not work for IPv6.

While there are lots of possible reasons, other than listening on loopback for security, these use cases are very rare and most users leave docker to listen on all interfaces.